bash script that would allow multiple users to login to my macOS machine on reboot
I would like to have a bash script that would login my users automatically (i have 3) bypassing the lockscreen each time my mac is rebooted (probably will use plist for this) instead of having to login with the users one by one. security isn't much of a concern and i don't mind the credentials being shown in the script, but I would still like to have my user/pass
let's assume i have user1, user2 and user3 and all have the same password 1234.
could this be done? right now i just want to test the script and user logs in. i tried the following script so far but it left me on the lock screen;
#!/bin/bash

USER="user1"
PASS="1234"

# Function to simulate user login using AppleScript
simulate_login() {
    local USER=$1
    local PASS=$2

    # AppleScript to simulate user login
    osascript <<EOF
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "$USER"
        keystroke return
        delay 1
        keystroke "$PASS"
        keystroke return
    end tell
EOF
}

simulate_login "$USER" "$PASS"

echo "Login simulation script executed."```


I would use expect for this.  expect is designed for this kind of thing. You could also do keyless entry:  https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/passwordless-ssh

What is the point of logging the users in automatically, or at all?

This might be of interest.

thank you @chepner that's actually very interesting and will test it out. in my case I need the users to be logged in to be able to run certain automation tests on my machine

@chepner unfortunately /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession has been deprecated so I cannot use what you highlighted and I'm not really sure if it's at all possible nowadays to achieve what I want due to MAC's security hardening.
